# How to debug Parse Error (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
     // chat poster

     $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=wordpower','root','bheq0913');

     //secure the chat
     if(isset($_POST['text'])&& isset($_POST['name'])){
        $text = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['text']));
        $name = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['name']));

        if(!empty($text) && !empty($name)){
                $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat VALUES('', '".$name"', '".$text"') ");
                $insert->execute();

                echo "<li class="cm"><b>".ucwords($name)."</b> - ".$text."</li>"; 
        }
     }

?>
```

Help me out of this error please, it says

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', '"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\webko\insert.php on line 12

Comment: You need 2 concatenation dots

Comment: It's incredibly bad practise to inject values directly into a prepared statements..... what's the point of using prepared statements if you're going to abuse them like that?

Comment: sir im newbie in php then i watch tutorials in youtube. but when i follow the tutorial and i code it. that error's come.